# How to Send Data to an sFTP server? and how to upload/download data to it?

Tags: linux, ftp, sftp

I am completely new to sFTP (Secure File Transfer Protocol) Servers and would like to know how to send data to one.

Imagine I have set up an sFTP server, could someone provide me with the pseudo code (as I am not sure what specifics I'm required to give) for sending a .zip file to it using a Linux box on the command line.

Also could you provide me with the pseudo code that would be needed to extract that same data once it has been uploaded from that server.

Could I please ask that any code supplied be heavily commented (as I really want to understand this!)

Please be gentle with your comments, I am VERY new to all of this. I imagine I will have missed out something key that someone will need to no. If any additional information is required please let me know and I will of course supply it.

Thanks in advance. I really will appreciate any help/advise!

Comment: "SFTP" is confusing -- SFTP is normally used to denote "SSH File Transfer Protocol", not "Secure ...". Some people use "SFTP" to describe FTP-over-SSL. So it's not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: You are correct, I ment to say FTPS.

Answer (score 0):

For a GUI, you need an SFTP client like FileZilla. There is a lot of them free.

Linux has a **sftp** command for bash.

Answer (score 0):

From your client, you can use `curl` to upload and/or download files to/from your sftp server.

To upload a file:

```
curl -T /name/of/local/file/to/upload -u username:password sftp://hostname.com/directory/to/upload/file/to
```

To download a file:

```
curl -u username:password sftp://hostname.com/name/of/remote/file/to/download -o /name/of/local/directory/to/download/file/to
```